# Why do two codes look the same, but one does not work ? Python linked list data structure 2

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

thanks in advance for reading the question.

I`m studying single linked list through Python, and below two methods pop(), pop1() troubles me.

class Node(object):

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None

def __repr__(self):
    nval = self.value and self.next.value or None
    return f"[{self.value}:{repr(nval)}]"
```

class LinkedListController(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.begin = None

# Appends new value at the end of the list
def push(self, obj):
    if not self.begin:
        self.begin = Node(obj)
    else:
        current_node = self.begin
        while current_node.next:
            current_node = current_node.next
        current_node.next = Node(obj)

# Removes the last item and returns it
def pop(self):
    if not self.begin:
        return None
    elif self.count() == 1:
        value_to_return = self.begin.value
        self.begin = None
        return value_to_return
    else:
        current_node = self.begin.next
        next_node = current_node.next
        while next_node:
            current_node = next_node
            next_node = current_node.next

        value_to_return = current_node.value
        current_node = None
        return value_to_return

def pop1(self):
    if not self.begin:
        return None
    elif self.count() == 1:
        value_to_return = self.begin.value
        self.begin = None
        return value_to_return
    else:
        r = self.begin
        while r.next.next:
            r = r.next
        value_to_return = r.next.value
        r.next = None
        return value_to_return

# Counts the number of elements in the list
def count(self):
    current_node = self.begin
    count = 0

    while current_node:
        count = count + 1
        current_node = current_node.next
    return count
```

Below is test code :

```
from unittest import TestCase
from data_structure.single_linked_list_without_endnode import LinkedListController as node_controller
```

class TestLinkedList(TestCase):

```
def test_pop(self):
    colors = node_controller()
    colors.push("Magenta")
    colors.push("Blaring Sun")
    colors.push("White sand")

    self.assertEquals(colors.pop(), "White sand")
    self.assertEquals(colors.pop(), "Blaring Sun")
    self.assertEquals(colors.pop(), "Magenta")
    self.assertEquals(colors.pop(), None)

    animals = node_controller()
    animals.push("Dog")
    animals.push("Cat")
    animals.push("Cow")

    self.assertEquals(animals.pop1(), "Cow")
    self.assertEquals(animals.pop1(), "Cat")
    self.assertEquals(animals.pop1(), "Dog")
    self.assertEquals(animals.pop1(), None)
```

Test result is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\projects\data_structure\tests\test_single_linked_list_without_endnode.py", line 27, in test_pop
    self.assertEquals(colors.pop(), "Blaring Sun") AssertionError: 'White sand' != 'Blaring Sun'
- White sand
+ Blaring Sun

It seems `current_node = None` part in pop() is not working, since it is still popping the last element, when it is supposed to do the second last element.

Q : Am I using references wrong way in pop() ?  Why does only pop1() work ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `current_node = None` you are just reassigning a local variable, it doesn't affect any of your objects.

The corresponding line `r.next = None` alters whatever object the variable `r` refers to.